# How can i send reminder message to customer before 2 hours in django/python

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am developing a web app for online ticket buying. I used telesign API to integrate sms system. Now i want a reminder system for my web app, it should send sms to customer before 2 hours of start time of movie.

Comment: take a look at message brokers (redis, rabbit-mq) und celery (beat)

Answer (score 2):

You could look at [periodic tasks](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#:~:text=celery%20beat%20is%20a%20scheduler,entries%20in%20a%20SQL%20database.) in celery.  You could run a task every 15 minutes (or whatever), and scan for imminent start times, and then send your SMS based on that.

If you are deploying to a Cloud platform such as AWS, then there are other mechanisms to achieve the same thing.